# how do i source .bashrc remotely

Tags: linux, scripting, ssh

I'm currently writing a script to set some PATH in a remote machine using ssh. I have successfully set the variables in the .bashrc. However, it the last step of my script is "source .bashrc". However, when i ssh to the machine manually, the PATH is still not set. What is the problem?

Comment: The .bashrc you've been working on is in the home directory of the remote machine, right?

Answer (score 1):

If on computer A, you set `PATH` with a script run via `ssh` on computer B, in a script, and then log in to computer B again, `PATH` will go back to what it was initially. The computer doesn't remember the value of `PATH` between processes, and it doesn't share it. `PATH` is an environment variable which is specific to each process. If you use

```
 export PATH
```

then it will be inherited by child processes, but here your second login session is not a child process of the first one.

Comment: what if i want to set some path by default when i login?